# Was told my C program was "hard coded" and I don't understand why

Tags: c, programming-languages

I turned in my assignment to my online C programming class and was docked huge due to the fact that my program was "hard coded, and I can't see how it would be considered "hard coded" as I ask for user input. The following was my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IMAX 3
#define JMAX 4

int main()
{   
    float a[IMAX][JMAX];
    float avgrow[5];
    float avgcol[5];
    int i,j;
    char c;

    printf ("This program will allow you to enter numbers for 3 rows and 4 columns from         left to right then filling down, and take the averages of the rows and columns and list them next to the row and under the columns. You may use decimals but only 2 will display in the results. Press enter!\n");
    scanf ("%c",&c);

    printf("Enter 12 numbers here for your rows and columns:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < IMAX; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
        {
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
    {
        avgrow[0] = (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[0][3])/JMAX;
        avgrow[1] = (a[1][0]+a[1][1]+a[1][2]+a[1][3])/JMAX;
        avgrow[2] = (a[2][0]+a[2][1]+a[2][2]+a[2][3])/JMAX;
    }
    for(i=0; i < IMAX; i++)
    {
        avgcol[0] = (a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0])/IMAX;
        avgcol[1] = (a[0][1]+a[1][1]+a[2][1])/IMAX;
        avgcol[2] = (a[0][2]+a[1][2]+a[2][2])/IMAX;
        avgcol[3] = (a[0][3]+a[1][3]+a[2][3])/IMAX;
    }

    printf("  Column1         Column2         Column3         Column4         Row Average\n\n");
    printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3],avgrow[0]);
    printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[1][0],a[1][1],a[1][2],a[1][3],avgrow[1]);
    printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[2][0],a[2][1],a[2][2],a[2][3],avgrow[2]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t\n",avgcol[0],avgcol[1],avgcol[2],avgcol[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

All it was supposed to do was make a 2-d array with 3 rows and 4 columns, then take the average of the rows and display that next to to the row in a table. Than take the average of the columns and display them beneath the columns in the table.

This was his comments on my assignment "Well, you got the correct answers, but when dealing with a 2-D array, you should use nested for loops. Not one for loop and then a lot of "hard coding" values into the program."

Any help deciphering this would be appreciated as I though I was finally understanding programming until this.

Comment: I think his `hard coding` comment is in respect to the 2d array. So if you want to change the size of that 2d array you'd have to go through and modify your source a huge amount. If you did a nested for loop you wouldn't have to change anything.

Comment: There is a place which produces a change in the program when you change the value(`IMAX 3`, `JMAX 4`).

Comment: You do notice that you don't use i and j in the loop bodies? Instead you literally enumerate all elements. That's what they mean.

Comment: The input loop was nice. Find out how to use i and j in a nested loop as indices when computing the averages. Or, rather stay with two single loops first and spell out the respective other index, then see the pattern and nest the loops.

Comment: The proper term for what you did is *loop unrolling*, not "hard coding". This trades off maintainability for performance.  You would have room to argue that you answered the question correctly if it wasn't stipulated that you had to use loops, or that the code had to easily accommodate different bounds.

Comment: Thank you, that was another point for me was that it was not in the instructions at all to use nested loops, nor in the text. I'm not going to fight it as these online classes are nearly impossible to appeal vice my normal classes, but I was expecting a decent grade as it met all the specs.....

Comment: yet thanks to a great community I definately see were this was not a great program I wrote and I how I could go about it much better in the future

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all it's not meaningful to talk about a program being hard coded or not. Rather one would talk about specific values being hard coded. What this means is that you wrote their values directly into the code rather than putting them in a constant or variable that can easily be changed.

In this case the values you hard-coded are the number of rows and the number of columns. You do have constants for these, but you don't use them consistently. That is if you changed your constants to turn the array into a 5x5 array, your code would now break because parts of the code would still act like it is an 3x4 array.

Specifically there are two loops in your code where you're accessing the indices [0][0] through [2][3] by spelling out each index in that range specifically rather than using a loop. This means that if you change IMAX and JMAX, it will still use those same indices, which aren't correct any more.

So your array indices are hard-coded and changing the array dimensions breaks your program.

Answer (score 5):

```
for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
{
    avgrow[0] = (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[0][3])/JMAX;
    avgrow[1] = (a[1][0]+a[1][1]+a[1][2]+a[1][3])/JMAX;
    avgrow[2] = (a[2][0]+a[2][1]+a[2][2]+a[2][3])/JMAX;
}
for(i=0; i < IMAX; i++)
{
    avgcol[0] = (a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0])/IMAX;
    avgcol[1] = (a[0][1]+a[1][1]+a[2][1])/IMAX;
    avgcol[2] = (a[0][2]+a[1][2]+a[2][2])/IMAX;
    avgcol[3] = (a[0][3]+a[1][3]+a[2][3])/IMAX;
}
```

Notice the copying/pasting of nearly identical code? That's often a sign of hardcoding -- the presence of constants in the code's text or structure. How do you change the 3 and the 4? They're "hard" -- built into the code.

The proof it's a problem -- you have:

```
#define IMAX 3
#define JMAX 4
```

But if you actually change those, the code will break. Look at this line of code:

```
    avgrow[0] = (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[0][3])/JMAX;
```

That's an average if, and only if, JMAX is 4. The code was build with the understanding that JMAX had to be 4 -- JMAX was "hard coded" to 4.

Comment: Copy & paste is bad too, but not a synonym for hardcoding.

Comment: You can copy&paste without hardcoding, and you can hardcode without copy&paste. But they very, very often point to the same thing. Any time you see copy&paste, you should strongly suspect hardcoding as the cause and removing the copy&paste will usually fix the hardcoding automatically.

Comment: That's not my impression. Also, just pulling the duplicated code into a single function does not fix hardcoding. It makes it easier to fix (a trivial fact, every change is easier with less redundancy). Anyway: Even if there's correlation, the two are separate phenomena and confusing them doesn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the following code:

```
for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
{
    avgrow[0] = (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[0][3])/JMAX;
    avgrow[1] = (a[1][0]+a[1][1]+a[1][2]+a[1][3])/JMAX;
    avgrow[2] = (a[2][0]+a[2][1]+a[2][2]+a[2][3])/JMAX;
}
```

This code assumes that `a` *always* has 3 rows and 4 columns, *regardless of how `a` was actually declared*.  If you changed `JMAX` to 2, for example, then your code above would break because `a` would have dimension 3x2, and you'd be attempting to access elements outside of the array bounds.

What your instructor was looking for was something along these lines:

```
for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
{
  float sum = 0.0;

  for (i = 0; i < IMAX; i++ )
  {
    sum += a[i][j];
  }
  avgrow[j] = sum/JMAX;
}
```

This code makes no assumptions about the dimensions of `a` beyond what is specified by `IMAX` and `JMAX`.

Note also that your declarations for `avgrow` and `avgcol` are hard-coded to `5`, when they should also be based on `IMAX` and `JMAX`:

```
float avgrow[IMAX];
float avgcol[JMAX];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float avgrow[5];
float avgcol[5];

for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
 {
    avgrow[0] = (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]+a[0][3])/JMAX;
   avgrow[1] = (a[1][0]+a[1][1]+a[1][2]+a[1][3])/JMAX;
   avgrow[2] = (a[2][0]+a[2][1]+a[2][2]+a[2][3])/JMAX;
}

for(i=0; i < IMAX; i++)

{
   avgcol[0] = (a[0][0]+a[1][0]+a[2][0])/IMAX;
   avgcol[1] = (a[0][1]+a[1][1]+a[2][1])/IMAX;
   avgcol[2] = (a[0][2]+a[1][2]+a[2][2])/IMAX; 
   avgcol[3] = (a[0][3]+a[1][3]+a[2][3])/IMAX;

}

printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3],avgrow[0]);
printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[1][0],a[1][1],a[1][2],a[1][3],avgrow[1]); 
printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\n",a[2][0],a[2][1],a[2][2],a[2][3],avgrow[2]);
printf("\n");
printf("%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t%8.2f\t\n",avgcol[0],avgcol[1],avgcol[2],avgcol[3]);
```

THESE ALL STEPS YOU HAVE TAKEN ARE HARD CODING AS YOU ARE SPECIFICALLY MENTIONING THE INDICES IF SUPOSE the value imax and jmax changes then you have to manually change/add avgcol[index] in taking averages as well as in output...

Your programm should be independent of it it should only depend on the value of i max and jamx

for a reference you can view a sample of  your code in which i have removed hardcoding

```
http://ideone.com/mXymKS
```

Although this code could be simplied to a great extent...

Comment: thank you I definitely see were I went wrong, I had originally tried to do the arithmetic on the array[i] and [j] part but couldn't get it to compile, now I can see what I did wrong as I was trying to do it by the whole line like avgrow[i] += array[i][j]/jmax or something to that effect (and yes i know that doesn't follow the order of operations), but see now I needed to break it down more to do this properly. This is a tough online course with limited instruction, So I truly appreciate all the feedback!!

Answer (score 1):

You have used explicit integer values for the array indices of `avgrow` and `avgcol`. To avoid hard-coding, try using a loop with an integer variable as index, e.g.,

> for(int k=0; k<4; ++k)

and then assign values to avgrow[k].

Comment: Why not use `JMAX`, as it's already defined, available, and serves the exact purpose? Hardcoding a 4 in this loop is only *slightly* better.

Comment: Jongware, that's a good point. My example should have used JMAX. My point was to introduce an index variable instead of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your professor expected you to be able to modify the number of line and columns in your program easily. The disadvantage of the program you wrote is that a modification of one of those two parameters require you to change the whole program. You can achieve more flexibility for instance like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IMAX 3
#define JMAX 4

int main()
{   
    float a[IMAX][JMAX];
    float avgrow[IMAX] = {0};
    float avgcol[JMAX] = {0};

    printf ("This program will allow you to enter numbers for %d rows"
            "and %d columns from left to right then filling down, and"
            " take the averages of the rows and columns and list them"
            " next to the row and under the columns. You may use "
            "decimals but only 2 will display in the results. Press"
            " enter!\n", IMAX, JMAX);
    char c;
    scanf ("%c",&c);

    printf("Enter %d numbers here for your rows and columns:\n", IMAX * JMAX);
    for(int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < JMAX; j++) {
            scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);     
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < JMAX; j++) {
            avgrow[i] += a[i][j];
        }
        avgrow[i] /= JMAX;
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < JMAX; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
            avgcol[j] += a[i][j];
        }
        avgcol[j] /= IMAX;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
        printf("Column%d\t", i);
    }
    printf("Row-Average\n\n");

    for(int j = 0; j < JMAX; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
            printf("%8.2f\t", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("%8.2f\n", avgrow[j]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++) {
        printf("%8.2f\t", avgcol[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the rich answers already exist, I'd like to point out something about `acquiring data` and `computing averages` without much repetitions :

So define your average arrays like this :

```
float avgrow[IMAX] ={0};
float avgcol[JMAX] ={0};
```

Then in the same loop where you `scanf` user's entries you can simultaneously compute averages like this:

```
printf("Enter %d numbers here for your rows and columns:\n", IMAX*JMAX);
for(i = 0; i < IMAX; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&a[i][j]);
        avgrow[i] += a[i][j]/JMAX;
        avgcol[j] += a[i][j]/IMAX;
    }
}
```

Next step is just to print out everything, and let it be automated too :)

```
for(i=1; i<= JMAX; i++) printf("Column%d\t\t", i);
printf("Row Average\n");
for(i=0; i<IMAX; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<JMAX; j++) 
    {
        printf("%8.2f\t", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("%8.2f\n", avgrow[i]);
}
for(i=0; i<JMAX; i++)
printf("%8.2f\t", avgcol[i]);
```

**By the END**
you have a code that computes row and col averages for any sizes. i.e. try changing `IMAX` or `JMAX`